# Use plyr to split, subset splits, then apply functions and combine

Tags: r, plyr

I want to know how to use plyr to split the data I have, then subset that split, *then* apply the functions I want, then combine everything again. An example can explain what I'm trying to do a bit better, I think.

Below is what I've been doing so far (with made up data). This just removes outliers, as defined by being greater than 2 standard deviations from the mean, from the entire dataset at the beginning.

```
library(plyr)

# create some random data
d <- data.frame(type1 = c(rep("A",100),rep("B",50),rep("C",50)), 
                type2 = c(rep("good",65),rep("bad",135)),
                values = rnorm(200, 10, 5))

# remove values more than 2 standard deviations from the mean
mu <- mean(d$values)
stdev <- sd(d$values)
d_nooutliers <- subset(subset(d, values > mu - 2*stdev), values < mu + 2*stdev)

# breakdown by type1 and type2
my_breakdown <- ddply(d_nooutliers, .(type1, type2), summarize,
                      mean = mean(values), sd = sd(values), n = length(values))
```

The problem is, the approach above removes the values that are outliers to the entire dataset. Instead, I want to remove the outliers from each split. For example, when plyr looks at the split for values of "A" and "good", I'd like to calculate the mean and standard deviation of the values in that group, *then* remove the outliers like the method above, then recalculate the mean and standard after removing the outliers and recombine everything.

It would be equivalent to running the code below. However, this is a manual way and I obviously want to use plyr because in my actual data a manual approach would be writing a lot of unnecessary code.

```
d_A_good <- subset(subset(d, type1 == "A"), type2 == "good")
d_A_mu <- mean(d_A_good$values)
d_A_stdev <- sd(d_A_good$values)
d_A_good_nooutliers <- subset(subset(d_A_good, values > d_A_mu - 2*d_A_stdev), 
                              values < d_A_mu + 2*d_A_stdev)
mean_i_want <- mean(d_A_good_nooutliers$values)
sd_i_want <- sd(d_A_good_nooutliers$values)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way of doing it with `dplyr` which is also faster than `plyr`:

```
require(dplyr)

d %>% 
  group_by(type1, type2) %>%
  mutate(mu = mean(values),
         stdev = sd(values)) %>%
  filter(values > mu - 2*stdev, values < mu + 2*stdev) %>%
  summarize(mu = mean(values),
            stdev = sd(values))

#Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
#Groups: type1
#
#  type1 type2       mu   stdev
#1     A   bad 10.399257 4.797609
#2     A  good  9.172753 3.905397
#3     B   bad 10.167619 4.748708
#4     C   bad  7.983228 4.613134
```

#### Edit

You can write it a bit shorter if you include what is in the mutate in the filter:

```
d %>% 
  group_by(type1, type2) %>%
  filter(values > mean(values) - 2*sd(values), 
         values < mean(values) + 2*sd(values)) %>%
  summarize(mu = mean(values),
            stdev = sd(values))
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Thanks boss, that's exactly what I needed. I have to look in to dplyr more!

Comment: Welcome. `dplyr` is definitely worth taking a good look and you can get started easily (that's at least my personal experience)

Comment: or `filter(abs(values - mean(values)) < 2 * sd(values))`